# Excel Dual Axis on same side

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible in Excel charting to present in a way such that instead of having a secondary axis, both axis reside on the same side?

Like this:

[image: pic]

Comment: You could probably fake it using two charts and aligning them in a specific way....  I don't think there's any built-in support for it.

Comment: @Tim, this can be done by changing the primary axis labels setting from 'Next to Axis' to 'High'.

Answer (score 3):

The following method will move the axis labels for both  series to the secondary axis:

- Create a line chart with your two series
- Set one of the series to be displayed on the secondary axis by selecting the series, right-clicking and choosing `Format Data Series`, and then changing the radio button from `Primary Axis` to `Secondary Axis`
- Select the primary series axis, right-click and choose `Format Axis`, and change the `Axis labels` setting from `Next to Axis` to `High`.
- You can then apply formatting, such as

  - Changing the text color of one or both series' axis labels to match the line color
  - Applying a custom number format to the primary series axis labels to move them farther to the left of the axis line. (I right-padded the custom format with spaces to achieve this).

[image: Chart and axis settings]

While on the subject, I should commend Jon Peltier's [thoughts](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/secondary-axes-in-charts-2/) on dual-scale charts. He prefers panel charts (stacked plot areas), largely because they are far less confusing to people.

Comment: New to me - I could have used that last week!